# Make the itemtext in a listview not show in full if it's a long text

Tags: android, listview

I have an listview and I need help with it. I'd like to keep the text in one "row" if would call it that.

So what I mean is, it doesnt matter how long the text is, if it's longer than the "witdh" then instead of showing the full text on two "rows" it should just fill that witdh and like, end it with ... or something else. The purpose of this is ofcourse so that all my rows in the listview are of the same size, or else it looks rlly amateurish and cheap ..

How can I do this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the TextView that holds the long text following attributes

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

This will ensure that long text is displayed in a single line end with "..." at the end.

Found in android doc: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)